# Is there any solution to remove spaces after striping text

Tags: python-3.x

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
raw_text = """<div style="margin: 0 0 15px 0;">
                    <b>Resident(s)</b><br>

                        <ul style="margin:0; padding:0;">

                                <li>
                                    Ramin Dev<br>

                                        (517) 947-6316<br>


                                        ramdin@gmail.com

                                </li>


                                <li>
                                    Beral Aroila<br>
                                    (404) 387-9871<br>

                                </li>

                        </ul>

                </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_text,"html.parser")
resident_text = soup.find("b",text="Resident(s)")
parent_resident = resident_text.parent
resident_text_b_text = parent_resident.find("b").extract()
print(parent_resident)
print("===========================")
for li in parent_resident.find_all("li"):
    print(li.text.strip().splitlines())
```

Required solution:
['Ramin Dev', '(517) 947-6316,'telahinafisa@gmail.com'],
['Beral Aroila', '(404) 387-9871']

But my solution is taking the tabs and the spaces. Is there any solution to remove that.

Comment: `print([s.strip() for s in li.text.splitlines() if s.strip()])`